# Div is making a margin by itself?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have 2 divs side by side and when i tried to put them in they just fall under eachother. One div is creating a margin on its own to push the others down, how to I get them side-by-side?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4yysd68/)

HTML:

```
    <div class="teams">
  <div class="team1">
    <img src="images/teams/prolific.png" style="height : 100%; width : 100%; position : relative; z-index : 1">
  </div>
  <p class="team_info">
    nothing</br>
    something
  </p>
</div>

<div class="teams">
  <div class="team2">
    <img src="images/teams/victory.png" style="height : 100%; width : 100%; position : relative; z-index : 1">
  </div>
  <p class="team_info">
    nothing</br>
    something
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div` elements are by default block level elements. giving width is not enough to make them "inline" elements. to do that, you need to change the `display` property to `inline-block`.

```
.teams {
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4yysd68/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block;` in parent class

.teams `{display: inline-block; margin: 0; width: 250px;}`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a code for you.try this.just copy and paste.this will help to you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">

   div.left{
    width:500px;
    height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px black;
   }

   div.left img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
   }

   div.right{
    width:500px;
    height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px black;

   }

     div.right img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
   }

</style>

<body>
 <div class="maindiv">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QGiJFumHUPo/maxresdefault.jpg">
        <p>your description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <img src="http://media1.santabanta.com/full1/Countries/Places/places-126a.jpg">
        <p>your descripion</p>
    </div>


 </div>

</body>
</html>
```